# Goodreads app (Scraping quotes) is it legal?

Tags: copyright

I like goodreads but it lacks many features, i want to develop an app that view quotes in more modern way with more advance filters and features .The app is free with the option to pay for extra features.
Is that legal or illegal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terms and condition for web scraping](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/terms-and-condition-for-web-scraping)

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Goodreads Terms of Use](https://www.goodreads.com/about/terms):

> No part of the Service may be reproduced, duplicated, copied, sold,
>   resold, visited, or otherwise exploited for any commercial purpose
>   without our express written consent....

...

> nothing in this Agreement shall be deemed to create a license in or
>   under any such intellectual property Rights, and you agree not to
>   sell, license, rent, modify, distribute, copy, reproduce, transmit,
>   publicly display, publicly perform, publish, adapt, edit or create
>   derivative works from any materials or content accessible on the
>   Service....

and

> Goodreads may permanently or temporarily terminate, suspend, or
>   otherwise refuse to permit your access to the Service without notice
>   and liability for any reason, including if in Goodreads' sole
>   determination you violate any provision of this Agreement, or for no
>   reason....

```
The app is free with the option to pay for extra features...
```

That makes no difference to Goodreads; the fact that it is an App and not simply a website that scrapes their content makes it more likely they will become aware of your usage, and possibly more likely they will take legal action against you.

The only way for you to legally use Goodreads content is to negotiate a license from them.